# Darktable custom framing

Tags: darktable

Is there a way to add custom matting/framing/borders preset instead of using the default rectangular ones?

I mean something like smooth corners or old fashion styles.

[image]

**Update:** The framing settings in darktable can add only rectangular borders to the photos. I have made few examples from [Snapseed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.niksoftware.snapseed) of custom setups.

[image: rectangular]
[image: dirty rectangular]
[image: smooth corners]
[image: old fashion]

Comment: Rounded corners require an alpha channel (or knowing the background upon which the image will be displayed). Because many of the image formats to which Darktable 'prints' (e.g. jpg) do not allow alpha channels, there is no way Darktable could produce consistent results for rounded corners. The other effects can probably be achieved using watermarks or otherwise combining images.

Comment: @benrudgers can you convert your comment into an answer? I think it is useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add such frames with the watermark module, as already mentioned in the comments. Use the alpha channel in the SVG file as well as the blurring features for shadows or other transparency effects. The only drawback is that the template has to match the size of the image, meaning that you need a template for every aspect ratio you want to work with. Here is an example, similar to your third example:

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: Where did you find that svg vector frame, Chris? I'm having trouble finding them for free on 'net.  Most are in eps format which we cant use?

Comment: I did it myself with Inkscape. That's pretty simple. The only drawback, as mentioned, is that you require one for each aspect ratio. With Inkscape you can read in eps files as well IIRC, and save as SVG.